# Insert json file into mongodb using a variable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert a json file into mongodb. When I enter the JSON directly into the insert statement, it works fine.  However, when I try to use the data variable from fs.readfile (same JSON) The insert fails.  I don't get an error, just now data in the collection when I use a variable instead of the raw JSON.  Here's the code..

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

 var fs = require('fs');
var mydocuments = fs.readFile('testNames.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var collection = db.collection('contactCollection');
     collection.insert(data, function(err, docs) { //This insert Fails
        collection.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log(format("count = %s", count));
            console.log("[" + data + "]" );
            db.close();
        });
    });

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

 var fs = require('fs');
var mydocuments = fs.readFile('testNames.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var collection = db.collection('contactCollection');
     collection.insert({firstname: "Bill"}, function(err, docs) { //This insert succeeds
        collection.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log(format("count = %s", count));
            console.log("[" + data + "]" );
            db.close();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're encoding the file's contents as a UTF-8 string and attempting to insert that into the database. You need to parse the string as JSON by using `JSON.parse()` before inserting the data.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mydocuments = fs.readFile('testNames.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
var collection = db.collection('contactCollection');
 collection.insert(JSON.parse(data), function(err, docs) { // Should succeed
    collection.count(function(err, count) {
        console.log(format("count = %s", count));
        console.log("[" + data + "]" );
        db.close();
    });
});
```