# Inserting a variable as a key in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am retrieving JSON data from an API and this is a short example of it:

```
{"hatenames":
    {"id":6239,
     "name":"hatenames",
     "stat1":659,
     "stat2":30,
     "stat3":1414693
    }
}
```

I am trying to insert it in the MongoDB (using **MongoClient**) but it won't let me put just the object directly or use a variable as a field name. If I put the var username it will just output it as username in the database field. This is what I would like to work:

```
collection.insert({object}
collection.insert({username:object[username]}
```

but it doesn't and I've been stuck on this for the past few hours. The only resolution I found was to set it and then update the field name afterwards, but that just seems lame to have to do every single time, is there no elegant or easy option that I am somehow missing?

Comment: What are you using to insert data in mongoDB, mongoose or MongoClient?

Comment: MongoClient, sorry for not specifying

Comment: When you do: console.log(hatenames['id']), are you able to get 6239?

Comment: If it were in a console.log or setting a variable yes, inserting doesn't even let me use [] without getting an error for unexpected '['..the JSON gets JSON.parse'd if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, being a programmer, you should forget about "it does not work" phrase. You should describe how it does not work with exact error messages you encounter. Not to your problem.

Just because I can easily do

```
db.coll.insert({"hatenames":
    {"id":6239,
     "name":"hatenames",
     "stat1":659,
     "stat2":30,
     "stat3":1414693
    }
})
```

or `var a = {"hatenames":{"id":6239, "name":"hatenames", "stat1":659, "stat2":30, "stat3":1414693}};` and `db.coll.insert(a)`,

I think that the problem is that your object is not really an object, but a string. So I suspect that you have a string returned to you back from that API. Something like `'{"hatenames":{...}'` and this caused a problem when you try to save it or access the properties. So try to convert it to JSON.

Comment: Thank you for answering, sorry if I didn't explain it properly. I actually JSON.parse the string as soon as I get it from the API. The problem is `db.coll.insert(a)` won't work, it won't allow me to input just a single var/object/thing, it will give me an error forcing me to do something like `db.coll.insert(a:b)`, making me input a key and than the value, hope that makes sense? At the same time, the key cannot be a variable, if I do `db.coll.insert(a:a)` the key will literally be "a" while the value will be the object a like you created, but under 'a' nonetheless

Comment: @HateNames can you please tell me what kind of an error you see in when you do `db.coll.insert(a)`

Comment: Wow I am so retarded. I noticed immediately when I read the error about to copy it for you, even though I've done that previously, many times but skipped the obvious part. I copied previous code from insert and was doing `db.coll.insert({a})` instead of `db.coll.insert(a)` ..what a waste of time, I am really sorry for troubling you guys. I'm so glad you fundamentally knew how it works, thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db_name', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    someCollection = db.collection('some_collection');
});

someCollection.insert({
    name: hatenames['name']
});
```

**EDIT**

For Dynamic approach, I would suggest you to play aroung this [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(hatenames)
```

this function will return keys in array.

**EDIT 2**

I have founded a link: [Insert json file into mongodb using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588916/insert-json-file-into-mongodb-using-a-variable)

See, if that helps.

Comment: That will work for sure, but I already knew I could add them like that and just do: `id: hatenames['id'], name: hatenames['name'], stat1: hatenames['stat1']` etc, the problem is this JSON is a short example of the real one, some have over 50 values and that would be crazy to do one by one like that,

Comment: Okay, so do you want more of a dynamic approach?

Comment: I would love something that works, but preferable not adding the entire thing and then going back to update the field/key name if possible

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Guarav Dave, I really appreciate how much you tried to help me, can't thank you enough. Unfortunately I was dumb and missed a really obvious flaw, Salvadador Dali helped me find my stupid syntax error, really sorry for wasting your time, thank you again for all your help

Comment: @HateNames It's okay, at least you have solution now!  :)